# Swift app returning a blank screen on ipads?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I tried uploading my first app yesterday (swiftui) and now got back an error saying that my app creates a blank screen on ipad. I didnt intend the app to be used on ipad but now when i checked it does indeed display a white blank screen. However it works on any iphone model.

How do i fix this? Or is there a way to only launch the app for iphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Uncheck iPad

[image]

This will still run the app on iPad, but just like it runs in iPhone(same frame.)